# BNC Connector/Cable Suggestion

Tags: connector, signal, cables, trigger, bnc

I am not an expert in this area and therefore need suggestion regarding what is the best way out for this case.

For my experiment, I am installing a camera that requires a BNC based trigger signal. In the manual, it suggests the properties as given in the picture:

[image]

From what I have known so far, there are usually 50 or 75 ohms BNC connectors and cables. Where can I find 1 kOhms available?

Second, what exactly LVTTL means? Previously, I was using 1.7 V rising edge required trigger signal.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For my experiment, I am installing a camera that requires a BNC based
>   trigger signal. In the manual, it suggests the properties as given in
>   the picture

The properties suggested in the manual are the properties of the BNC input port i.e. the port accepts an (LV) TTL signal with a rise time greater than 1 volt per millisecond and presents an impedance to the trigger signal of typically 1 kohm.

LV = low voltage. Various TTL signal level standards: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/f/138/t/189611?Input-levels-for-LVDS-driver)

Answer (score 3):

LVTTL is low voltage TTL (and TTL is transistor-transistor logic).  LVTTL runs at 3.3V instead of the usual 5V.  The "5V tolerant" means it doesn't mind being fed conventional 5V TTL if needed.

You won't find a 1kΩ BNC plug.  Don't worry about it.  It's just an "arm" signal, so impedance matching won't be critical.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't have much idea about what an "arm" signal really is. In the camera manual it states that it is used to get the camera ready. That's all I know about it so far.